# Hhow to add Multiple Checkboxes to table using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating simple inventory control system using jquery and php. There are three checkboxes. If I check more than one checkbox and click the add button the checked item is not added into the table. I   attached screen shot image along with the code.
For example I checked the 'roll' and 'bun' checkboxes and enter the qty and they should be added the table, but they are not.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
    var check = $("input[name='pos']:checked").val();
    var price = null;
    if (check == "Roll") {
      price = 12;
    } else if (check == "Bun") {
      price = 15;
    } else if (check == "Pasty") {
      price = 35;
    }
    var qty = $('#qty').val();
    tot = qty * price;
    var table1 =
      "<tr>" +
      "<td><button type='button' name='record' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='deleterow(this)'>Delete </td>" +
      "<td>" + radio1 + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + price + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + qty + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + tot + "</td>" +

      "</tr>";
    total += Number(tot);
    $('#total').val(total);


    $("table tbody").append(table1);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm-project">

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">

      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="pos" id="pos" value="Roll">
      <label>Roll</label>
      <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty" size="10px">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">

      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="pos" id="pos" value="Bun">
      <label>Bun</label>
      <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty" size="10px">
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">

      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="pos" id="pos" value="Pasty">
      <label>Pasty</label>
      <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty" size="10px">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="ADD">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Reset" name="reset" id="reset">

  </div>

</form>


<table id="tbl-item" class="table table-dark table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Delete</th>
      <th>Item</th>

      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Total</th>



    </tr>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Also post your form  where do you submit your data, just to see if you `serialize` the for before to `submit()`

Comment: i didn't send any data. i need to calculate using jquery code i written the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

- Undefined variables `total` and `radio1` that should be `check`.
- Your selector returns a collection, but `val()` can't operate on collections so it returns just the first value. You should loop them using
  [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/).
- Same thing happens with the quantity, you select it by `id`, and `id`s should be unique in the document so it's returning the first
  element found. You can select it using
  [`.siblings('[name="qty"]')`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
- `.val()` only works with form controls. To update the total you should use `.text()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let total = 0;  // Declare the variable
  $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
    // Loop over all checked elements
    $("input[name='pos']:checked").each(function() {
      // Get the value
      let check = $(this).val();
      var price = null;
      if (check == "Roll") {
        price = 12;
      } else if (check == "Bun") {
        price = 15;
      } else if (check == "Pasty") {
        price = 35;
      }
      // Get the quantity
      var qty = $(this).siblings('[name="qty"]').val();
      tot = qty * price;
      var table1 =
        "<tr>" +
        "<td><button type='button' name='record' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='deleterow(this)'>Delete </td>" +
        "<td>" + check + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + price + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + qty + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + tot + "</td>" +

        "</tr>";
      total += Number(tot);
      // Update total
      $('#total').text(total);
      $("table tbody").append(table1);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm-project">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="pos"  value="Roll">
      <label>Roll</label>
      <input type="number" name="qty" size="10px">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="pos" value="Bun">
      <label>Bun</label>
      <input type="number" name="qty" size="10px">
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="pos" value="Pasty">
      <label>Pasty</label>
      <input type="number" name="qty" size="10px">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="ADD">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Reset" name="reset" id="reset">
  </div>

</form>


<table id="tbl-item" class="table table-dark table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Delete</th>
      <th>Item</th>

      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>

<div>
Total: <span id="total"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="pos[]" id="pos" value="Roll" >
        <label>Roll</label>
         <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty"  size="10px" >
        </div>
       <div class="form-check">

       <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="pos[]" id="pos" value="Bun" >
         <label>Bun</label>
         <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty"  size="10px" >
       </div>

        <div class="form-check">

         <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="pos[]" id="pos" value="Pasty" >
         <label>Pasty</label>
          <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty"  size="10px" >
         </div>
        </div>
```

After that you can access your `array $_POST['pos']`

to get all checkboxes which are checked try this:

```
$('.form-check-input:checkbox:checked')
```

will give you all the checked checkboxes with the class theClass
to get calculate data from your checkboxes do this:

```
$('.form-check-input:checkbox.class').each(function () {
       var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
  });
```

Comment: @nishan kishan you have posted a names in your checkboxes like a `name="pos"` but you have to use array `name="pos[]"`

Comment: var check = $("input[name='pos[]']:checked").val(); sir i correct it only one data added into the table

Comment: i tried but it is not working. i checked the mulipule item and click add button item should add into the table sir

Comment: @nishan kishan now in `var sThisVal` you going to have all checkbox data which are checked.